# create object in thread and pass sockets WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

i need to create an object in thread and pass to him sockets to send message but when i create the object the connected status in the object is false. and i cant send message
someone can help me?

this is my code:

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
 {
       game = new Game(clientStream);
       game.setGame(message);
       game.Client = clientStream;
       this.Close();
       game.ShowDialog();
 }));
```

this how i create the thread in the constractur

```
    ThreadStart checkForActions = new ThreadStart(checkForCloseOrStart);
    actions = new Thread(checkForActions);
    actions.Start();
```

and this is the whole thread function

```
    bool keepListening = true;

    while (keepListening)
    {
        try
        {
            string code = "";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            string msg = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                code += msg[i];
            }
            string[] message = code.Split('#');
            if (message[0] == "108")
            {
                int j = 0;
                string[] users = new string[message.Length - 2];
                for (int i = 2; i < message.Length; i++)
                {
                    users[j] = message[i];
                    j++;
                }
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    usersList.ItemsSource = users;
                }));
            }
            else if (message[0] == "116")
            {
                keepListening = false;
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.Close();
                }));
            }
            else if (message[0] == "118")
            {
                keepListening = false;
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    game = new Game(clientStream);
                    game.setGame(message);
                    game.Client = clientStream;
                    this.Close();
                    game.ShowDialog();
                }));
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is running constantly and not doing anything.  You are running through the while loop forever.  Remove the while loop.  Then call method after receiving data.

Comment: it end eventually because there is two if that change keeplistening to false

Comment: You cannot process data until you receive all the data.  The while loop doesn't solve the waiting.  Your code will fail if you only get a portion of the data.

Comment: can you show me how i can do that? i dont understnad

Comment: See the msdn aynchronous examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples